# Response.WriteFile() Strange characters issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, utf

Hello in my aspx page using MVC 3, I have the following code:

```
<%Response.WriteFile("/Content/Bing.htm"); %>
```

Which is an include file that contains BING search box code.

At the top of the containing DIV, a strange character is appearing:

ï»¿

I realize it it probably a BOM Byte Order Marker, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why it is showing up and how to get rid of it.  The rest of the bing code shows up and works fine.

Basically I want to be able to include htm files in my aspx pages.

any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably it's in the file. Edit the file in a *binary* file editor, and you should be able to see and remove it. Alternatively, read in the file in with something like `File.ReadAllText` and then write out the string to the response. I'd expect that to strip the BOM - and have the additional benefit of using a consistent encoding in the response, even if you have files of different encodings. (You'd need to specify the encoding when reading them, of course.)

Comment: @Cyberdrew: I've used frhed before now - there are loads, and for basic uses they're all likely to be fine.

Comment: Ah, the one in Visual Studio, figured it out. Thanks!